# PyQGIS adding layer with auth config ID leaks into project

Tags: pyqgis, authentication

I add a layer using an authentification config ID using PyQGIS:

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(HOST, PORT, DB, None, None, QgsDataSourceUri.SslPrefer, pg_auth_id)
QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "mylayer", "postgres")
```

In the project, the credentials are written in clear text in the project file:

```xml
<datasource>dbname='pub' host=geodb.rootso.org port=5432 user='xxxxxx' password='xxxxxx'
```

Is it possible to avoid this? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to call `QgsDataSourceUri.uri` with `False`:

`QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "mylayer", "postgres")`

see docs: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDataSourceUri.html#qgis.core.QgsDataSourceUri.uri